# ¿Que significa "mesón"?

Tags: significado, sustantivos, literatura

Estaba leyendo [*El amor en los tiempos del cólera*](https://www.wattpad.com/456326612-el-amor-en-los-tiempos-del-c%C3%B3lera-cap%C3%ADtulo-1) de García Márquez. No estoy seguro de lo que significa el sustantivo ***mesón*** en el siguiente contexto:

> Había ****un mesón*** atiborrado de frascos y pomos sin rótulos, y dos cubetas de peltre descascarado bajo un foco ordinario cubierto de papel rojo.

Aquí, supongo que [***mesón***](https://es.thefreedictionary.com/mes%C3%B3n) significa [un mostrador](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mostrador). Pero también se me ocurrió que la palabra puede significar un lugar de comidas. ¿Qué piensan?

Comment: El apellido completo del autor es García Márquez. De acuerdo a la costumbre hispana, el nombre completo de una persona incluye el apellido paterno y el apellido materno. En el habla corriente es posible referirse a alguien empleando solamente con el apellido paterno. Y si se quiere ser más formal se usan los dos apellidos. En este caso García es el apellido paterno y Márquez el materno.

Comment: @Javier Gracias por tu commentario, ya corrigí mi pregunta.

Answer (score 4):

Mesón en Colombia, de donde es García Márquez, se usa para referirse a las mesas que están en la cocina y que son de algún material resistente. Pueden ser cemento y ladrillo, revestido con cerámica, pero pueden ser de mármol, madera, acero inoxidable, etc. En las casas más antiguas toda las estructura era de cemento, y seguramente en alguna parte del mesón estaría el lavaplatos, en otra parte habría un espacio para poner la estufa, etc.

En el caso de la lectura, se trata de un laboratorio, en donde también se usan mesones porque los materiales que se emplean pueden ser corrosivos y dañar una mesa normal. El antillano era fotógrafo de niños, luego ese era su laboratorio y esos frascos sin rótulo y demás, los reactivos que el antillano usaba en sus labores de revelado.

Answer (score 2):

Yo diría que mesón = mesa grande, en base a que es lo que por el contexto parece significar.

Por otro lado, el [Diccionario de americanismos](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=meson) da las siguientes definiciones para **mesón**:

> I. 1.  m. *Co, Ve, Bo:O, Ch, Py. En una cocina*, mesa hecha de ladrillos, cemento y arena, *generalmente revestida de cerámica*, que se utiliza para preparar alimentos.
> 2.  *Bo:O, Ch, Py.* Mostrador de un establecimiento público.
> 3.  *Ec. En una cocina*, mesa adosada que sirve para preparar alimentos o poner electrodomésticos.

Comment: Si, soy chileno, allá mesón es mesa grande, pero no una mesa grande para comer, sino para trabajar o preparar cosas, aunque también puedes comer en el mesón pero no es su uso original.